# Change category title in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

I am running an online store based on OpenCart and I want to add something more to the category titles. For example, right now I have a category called Electronics. The title is simple: Electronics. I want to add, for example, the text "Buy" in the title, in front of the category name.

Anyone has an idea about how I can achieve that ?

Comment: You want to add different text to each category or one constant to all categories (example: Adding "Buy" in front of every category, or just one)?

Comment: Name the category Buy Electronics??

Answer (score 2):

if you have a multi language  use these steps:

1. Edit: *"/catalog/language/"**languageFolder**"/product/category.php"* add this>

   `$_['text_buy'] = 'Buy ';`
2. Edit: *"/catalog/controller/product/category.php"*
   after

> *$data['text_sale'] = $this->language->get('text_sale');*
> (line 120)

`$data['text_buy'] = $this->language->get('text_buy');`

3. Edit the template file category.tpl located at *catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/*
   Open file in step 1 in editor and locate

   around line 17
4. Replace line in step 2 with `<h2><?php echo $text_buy .  $heading_title; ?></h2>`
   or `<h2><b><?php echo $text_buy ?></b><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>`

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the template file *category.tpl* located at *catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/*
2. Open file in step 1 in editor and locate `<h2><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>` around line 17
3. Replace line in step 2 with `<h2><?php echo 'Buy ', $heading_title; ?></h2>`
4. Save file and test